# Suggestion for MATLAB statistical pattern recognition toolbox?

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition

I am looking for a pattern recognition toolbox in MATLAB capable of doing well and have enough number of possible routines. What can be good candidate?

Comment: Kevin Murphy's [probabilistic modeling toolkit is nice](http://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/)

Answer (score 1):

I like SPIDER, but just because it has cool graphics.  It isn't a bad SVM and it can do some basics.

When it comes to pattern recognition, there are a lot of flavors of algorithms to choose from and each has its own trade-offs.  The kinds of patterns that you are trying to work with determine which methods are going to work better.  Without a clear specification there, it is somewhat difficult to make more headway into recommending a particular direction.